# Максимальное значение строки mysql

Tags: mysql

Какое максимальное значение может быть в строке mysql? Например (name VARCHAR (??????????)

Comment: Values in VARCHAR columns are variable-length strings. The length can be specified as a value from 0 to 255 before MySQL 5.0.3, and 0 to 65,535 in 5.0.3 and later versions. The effective maximum length of a VARCHAR in MySQL 5.0.3 and later is subject to the maximum row size (65,535 bytes, which is shared among all columns) and the character set used.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13506832/what-is-the-mysql-varchar-max-size

Comment: То есть, можно сохранить как минимум 65000 символов?(1 байт на символ)

Comment: Что значит максимальное? У строки есть фиксированная длина, она может быть не больше чем размер поля.

Comment: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Column_types.html